# What is the point of Virtual replace mode in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

The help says that virtual replace mode commands in Vim `gr` & `GR` replace characters in screen estate and not in file.

```
:help Virtual-Replace-mode
```

I am understanding this as something like changing the characters on the display but not in the buffer itself. Is that right? It seems incorrect.

I can use an explanation and probably a scenario or an example where this feature is relevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Virtual-Replace-Mode the Buffer is harder fixed to its origin position.

```
1. Hello World
         ^ Cursor
2. I like cheese
3. And beer
```

When entering normal replace mode and hitting `Internet<CR>And others` the new buffer will be like this:

```
1. Hello Internet
2. And others
3. I like cheese
4. And beer
```

When doing the same in Virtual-Replace the result will be

```
1. Hello Internet
2. And othersese
3. And beer
```

Another example (tabstop=2;sts=0):

```
1. 012345678901234567890
2. Hello beautiful World
         ^ Cursor
```

Pressed keys: `<Tab><Tab>`

Replace-Mode result:

```
1. 012345678901234567890
2. Hello     autiful World
```

Virtual-Replace-Mode result:

```
1. 012345678901234567890
2. Hello     tiful World
```

Because in Replace mode the replacement is done char by char, where `Tab` is one char, no matter how many chars are displayed. In Virtual-Replace-Mode visible length of the `Tab` (`:h 'ts'`, `:h 'sts'`) is used to replace the chars.